# Dynamic Datatemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a requirement that based on the User who logged in to my application I need to show a different view. How can I achieve this using datatemplates?

Thanks,
Jithu

Comment: Hi, could you be a little more specific?  Is this a Windows User account or application-specific account (ie does your application maintain a list of users)?  Is there a specific property of the account that you use to determine the view?  What type of view/control do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have Resource Dictionaries in the root of your WPF project like these for each User group/type:

- UserOneResources.xaml
- UserTwoResources.xaml
- ...

Which contains DataTemplates:

```
<!-- UserOneResources.xaml -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" />
</DataTemplate>

<!-- UserTwoResources.xaml -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in the constructor of your App.xaml.cs you can select appropriate resource dictionary for the current user type like the following:

```
public App()
{
    string resourceDictionaryToUse;

    if (user.Type = UserType.One)
    {
        resourceDictionaryToUse = "UserOneResources.xaml";
    }
    else
    {
        resourceDictionaryToUse = "UserTwoResources.xaml";
    }

    var rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + resourceDictionaryToUse) };

    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
}
```

Hope this helps.